# Runtime directive used on component with non-element root node. The directives will not function as intended

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I am upgrading vue2 to vue3 and I get the folowing warning in my console :

```
[Vue warn]: Runtime directive used on component with non-element root node. The directives will not function as intended. at <VNavigationDrawer modelValue=false onUpdate:modelValue=fn app="" > at <SideBar> at <VApp id="inspire" > at <App>
```

does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 6):

First node in the `<template>` must be a div (*or some other valid element, but div works for me, so...*)

```
<template>
    <div>
        ...
    </div>
</template>
```

If you add somethins else into  but outside of the wrapping `<div>`, this error occurs.

I do not know what, if any, offending nodes may be, but I do know that adding something between closing `</div>` and closing `</template>` triggers this error.